# Does islam permit to nikah with cousin's daughter?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

We know that Nieces are prohibited to marry...but is it halal to marry with the daughter of cousin and we also know that SAW 's cousin was Hazrat Ali and he married with bibi fatimah

Answer (score 0):

Your cousin is non-mahram and permissible to marry, so it should be clear that your cousins children would also be permissible provided both parents are non-mahram to you.