# Can anyone marry with her father's cousin?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

Is it permissible to marry with father's cousin? Means the nephew of her own grandmother

Comment: It is disliked to ask the same question twice on SE.

Answer (score 0):

This is the same situation as asked here: [Does islam permit to nikah with cousin's daughter?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51703/does-islam-permit-to-nikah-with-cousins-daughter)

And I would say the answer is similar. Your farther's cousins are non-mahram to him and permissible to marry (if female), so it should be clear that your farther's cousins would also be permissible for you to marry provided they are non-mahram to both your parents.

It makes no difference that your fathers cousin is male of female for the relationship distance is the same regardless of being male or female, so he is non-mahram to you.

Comment: If a question has an answer elseweher it is better not to answer so that we may easily delete or close it.